# jQuery and IE 11 Invalid operand to 'in'

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

We have an application, and when I test it in IE11, it show this

Invalid operand to 'in': Object expected  and it is pointing to jQuery,

We are using version 3.3.1

can somebody point to me what should I change on our code to fix this?

Currently I am looking in our code who has "in" operator like this

```
if ('rec_pattern' in tval) {
        data.rec_pattern = tval.rec_pattern;
    } else {
        data.rec_pattern = "";
    }
```

but I am not sure if this part of the code  need to adjust

Comment: Wouldn't really make much sense having that property on a jQuery object. Can try `Object#hasOwnProperty()` but without more context hard to help more. Please provide a [mcve] that reproduces issue

Comment: How is jquery related to this? Is `tval` a jquery object? data?

Comment: this is what it shows on IE 11, on other browsers even edge is OK

https://imgur.com/a/CHlc5ap

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to copy the `rec_pattern` property from `tval` to `data` then you can just do this:

```
data.rec_pattern = tval.rec_pattern || '';
```

Comment: this is what it shows on IE 11, on other browsers even edge is OK 
https://imgur.com/a/CHlc5ap